# Set column value via script in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to index my google sheet, based on an if condition. So, if the 3 column data is not empty, I want the first column of the sheet to get indexed. In the code below, the if statement is working fine, but I am unable to set the value of index in the first column.

```
var sheetFrom = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("production");
var data = sheetFrom.getDataRange().getValues();
var count = 0; 
var farmerCount = 0;
for(n=3;n<data.length;++n){ // iterate in the array, row by row
      if (data[n][2]!=""){
        farmerCount++; 
        data[n][0].setValue(farmerCount); 
        //sheetFrom.getRange(n, 0).setValue(farmerCount);
       }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Range indexing in Google Apps Script is 1 based so you want to use

```
sheetFrom.getRange(n, 1).setValue(farmerCount);
```

Possibly `n+1` depending on how many header rows you have.

Comment: Thanks, this is the mistake I was making.